# How to set a value taken from the database to a label in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using **C# MVC razor** to my project. I'm in beginner level in this technology. What I do here is **display some details** **taken from the database**. I have decided to use some usual way to display details. Without using keywords like "**@Html.LabelFor**" I have used the below code.

```
<label id="SID" name="SID" type="text" class="validate"></label>
```

Now I expect to display a detail called "SID" in this label. I have created the controller and taken the details also. But I couldn't find how to show details in a label. So please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the data from your db in your action method and pass it to the view where you use it to set the label text. You can use a view model to pass this info or ViewBag or you can simply pass this value if that is the only thing you want to pass.

Here is an example

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  string myLabelText="Read this from db";
  return View((object)myLabelText);  // Thanks Stephen for the comments
}
```

Now in the view which is strongly typed to string

```
@model string
<label id="SID" name="SID" class="validate">@Model</label>
```

Usuaully you might want to send more than one item from your view. In such cases, you might consider the view model approach. Create a view model class first.

```
public class MyPageVm
{
  public string MyLabelText { set;get;}
  public string MyLabelText2 { set;get;}
}
```

and in the action

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var vm = new MyPageVm();
  vm.MyLabelText="Read this from db";
  vm.MyLabelText2="Another one to read from db";
  return View(vm);
}
```

Now since we are passing an object of `MyPageVm` class,we need to make our view strongly typed to that.

```
@model MyPageVm
<label id="SID" name="SID" class="validate">@Model.MyLabelText</label>
<label id="SID2" name="SID2" class="validate">@Model.MyLabelText2</label>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for the answer. I will accept your answer in few minutes. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: With the first code snippet, it needs to be `return View((object)myLabelText);` otherwise an exception will thrown (because it tries to find a view that matched the value of `myLabelText`)

Comment: Yes. Good catch. Thanks. I guess if works if you use the overload which takes the view name and model object.

Comment: Actually, you still need to cast to an object because otherwise it calls [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.String%29) :)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Included your original casting solution to the answer.